# How does [(ngModel)] works with Unidirectional data flow in Angular 2

Tags: angular, 2-way-object-databinding

Angular 2 supports unidirectional data flow, one way at a time. How does two way data binding [(ngModel)] works in Angular2 ?

Answer (score 3):

Angular2 comprehends `[(ngModel)] = myName` as a `property + event` binding and as a collapsed version of,

1. `[ngModel] = 'myName'`, and
2. `(ngModelChange) = 'updateMyNameValue(myName)'`

Their `unidirectional data flow` policy might as well as take the expanded version of it such as setting the scope variable explicitly by the `inputs` event when the value is changed and vice-versa, so as this syntactic sugar version of it might look almost like

```
myName = '';
function updateMyNameValue(elem) {
   // find scope variable of `myName` and update it
   // find element in view and update it
}
// <input type="text" onchange="updateMyNameValue(this)" value="" />
```

According to the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html),

> `[(ngModel)]` is a specific example of a more general pattern in which
>   Angular "de-sugars" the `[(x)]` syntax into an `x` input property for
>   property binding and an `xChange` output property for event binding.
>   Angular constructs the event property binding's template statement by
>   appending `=$event` to the literal string of the template expression.
>
> ```
> [(x)]="e" <==> [x]="e" (xChange)="e=$event"
> ```

Comment: so, where does the event handler being implemented ? inside the component ?

Comment: @Shivanka No, they have their own way for each form controls such as `inputs, selects, multiple selects, etc..` to implement the event handler in their directives.

Comment: in a situation where I want to override the event handler in two way data binding, how do I implement such a functionality.

Comment: @Shivanka You can set the event handler explicitly by setting `(ngModelChange)`. If you're still unclear what I'm talking about, try clicking the docs link I gave.. It might help.